# How do I add a channel token embedding in vision Transformer TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, transformer-model

I am trying to create a specific version of a Vision Transformer, where *patch tokens are generated for each individual channel, utilizing a learnable channel embedding* **chn** *to preserve channel-specific information. The positional embeddings* **pos** *and the linear projection* **W** *are shared across all channels,* like shown in the picture below.

[Channel ViT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWZ3r.png)

I already have created my simple ViT, but cannot understand how to modify it to get the desired result.

My input is a data tensor (400, 40, 20, 32) (samples, Heigth, Width, Channels) and I have another tensor of 400 corresponding labels.
This is the code that I am using. The important parts for this, are the PatchEncoder and the Create_VisionTransformer functions:

```
class PatchExtractor(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PatchExtractor, self).__init__()

    def call(self, images):
        batch_size = tf.shape(images)[0]
        patches = tf.image.extract_patches(
            images=images,
            sizes=[1, 5, 5, 1],
            strides=[1, 5, 5, 1],
            rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
            padding="VALID",
        )
        patch_dims = patches.shape[-1]
        patches = tf.reshape(patches, [batch_size, -1, patch_dims])
        return patches
    
#%env TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR cuda_malloc_async




class PatchEncoder(Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_patches=16, projection_dim=800):
        super(PatchEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.num_patches = num_patches
        self.projection_dim = projection_dim
        w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        class_token = w_init(shape=(1, projection_dim), dtype="float32")
        self.class_token = tf.Variable(initial_value=class_token, trainable=True)
        self.projection = Dense(units=projection_dim)
        self.position_embedding = Embedding(input_dim=num_patches+1, output_dim=projection_dim)

    def call(self, patch):
        batch = tf.shape(patch)[0]
        # reshape the class token embedins
        class_token = tf.tile(self.class_token, multiples = [batch, 1])
        class_token = tf.reshape(class_token, (batch, 1, self.projection_dim))
        # calculate patches embeddings
        patches_embed = self.projection(patch)
        patches_embed = tf.concat([patches_embed, class_token], 1)
        # calcualte positional embeddings
        positions = tf.range(start=0, limit=self.num_patches+1, delta=1)
        positions_embed = self.position_embedding(positions)
        # add both embeddings
        encoded = patches_embed + positions_embed
        return encoded
    




class MLP(Layer):
    def __init__(self, hidden_features, out_features, dropout_rate=0.1):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        self.dense1 = Dense(hidden_features, activation=tf.nn.gelu)
        self.dense2 = Dense(out_features)
        self.dropout = Dropout(dropout_rate)

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        y = self.dropout(x)
        return y
    





class Block(Layer):
    def __init__(self, projection_dim, num_heads=4, dropout_rate=0.1):
        super(Block, self).__init__()
        self.norm1 = LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.attn = MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=projection_dim, dropout=dropout_rate)
        self.norm2 = LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.mlp = MLP(projection_dim, projection_dim, dropout_rate)

    def call(self, x):
        # Layer normalization 1.
        x1 = self.norm1(x) # encoded_patches
        # Create a multi-head attention layer.
        attention_output = self.attn(x1, x1)
        # Skip connection 1.
        x2 = Add()([attention_output, x]) #encoded_patches
        # Layer normalization 2.
        x3 = self.norm2(x2)
        # MLP.
        x3 = self.mlp(x3)
        # Skip connection 2.
        y = Add()([x3, x2])
        return y
    
class TransformerEncoder(Layer):
    def __init__(self, projection_dim, num_heads=2, num_blocks=1, dropout_rate=0.1):
        super(TransformerEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.blocks = [Block(projection_dim, num_heads, dropout_rate) for _ in range(num_blocks)]
        self.norm = LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.dropout = Dropout(0.5)

    def call(self, x):
        # Create a [batch_size, projection_dim] tensor.
        for block in self.blocks:
            x = block(x)
        x = self.norm(x)
        y = self.dropout(x)
        return y




def create_VisionTransformer(num_classes=1, num_heads=3, num_blocks=12, num_patches=16, projection_dim=800, input_shape=(40, 10, 32)):
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    # Patch extractor
    patches = PatchExtractor()(inputs)
    # Patch encoder
    patches_embed = PatchEncoder(num_patches, projection_dim=projection_dim)(patches)
    # Transformer encoder
    representation = TransformerEncoder(projection_dim = projection_dim, num_heads=num_heads, num_blocks=num_blocks)(patches_embed)
    representation = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(representation)
    # MLP to classify outputs
    #logits = MLP(projection_dim, num_classes, 0.5)(representation)
    logits = Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid')(representation)
    # Create model
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=logits)
            return model
```